# Why do we not need Christoffel to differentiate contravariant component of a vector?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

OK, perhaps a very stupid question but I am going nuts thinking about it. In page-106 of Pavel Grinfeld's Tensor Calculus book, we consider a vector $V= V^i Z_i$ and we consider the derivative of this expression with coordinates $Z^j$, we have:

$$ \frac{\partial V}{\partial Z^j} =  \frac{\partial V^i}{\partial Z^j} Z_i + V^i \frac{\partial Z_i}{\partial Z^j} \tag{1}$$

Now to differentiate the second term, the covariant basis, we use the Christoffel symbols defined as:

$$\Gamma_{jm}^k Z_k = \frac{\partial Z_i}{\partial Z^j}$$

In equation one , in the first term, $V^i$ a component of a $(1,0)$ tensor, but no Christoffel's came when differentiating it. Why is that? Conceptually speaking it is clear what Christoffel's are but I am having an algorithmic hangup here..

Comment: Your second equality is "false" due to a messy choice of indexes: there is a summation over $i$ on the LHS, not on the RHS

Comment: I am confused, there is upper and lower index hence a sum on LHS, no? @Didier

Comment: There is a contraction over $k$ but $i,j$ need to make an appearance on both sides $\frac{\partial \mathbf{Z}_i}{\partial Z^j}=\Gamma^k_{ij}\mathbf{Z}_k$. I think you are mixing up the partial derivative $\frac{\partial }{\partial Z^j}$ with the covariant derivative $\nabla_j$. They are not the same thing (most of the time). And the $\Gamma$ from the partial derivative of the basis vectors is just a definition.

Comment: Ahhh I had unwrapped it in the right way in my head but messed up when writing. I've fixed it now @ContraKinta

Comment: @Buraian . Eq. (1) you can view as a product rule applied to $V^iZ_i$ . You seem to be familiar with the definition of Christoffel symbol (your 2nd equation). Therefore I do not really understand the question why in term one in equation (1) they don't appear.

Comment: Oh right, it's just that I didn't plug in the definition of Christ symbols intoo the eqtn. My point is that the component it self is a tensor, so shouldn't we need Christoffels to differentiate it @KurtG.

Comment: Sounds like that confusion is coming from the notation you are using. I would replace the first $\frac{\partial}{\partial Z^j}$ in Eq. (1) by $D_j$ or $\nabla_j$.

Comment: How that fi the issue? @KurtG.

Comment: Then I may have misunderstood. What exactly *is* the issue ?

Comment: I am simply saying both component and basis are components of a (1,0) and (0,1) tensor. So, we have used Christoffels to differentiate the basis, so wouldn't we require that for the component as well? @KurtG.

Comment: I think Buraian is wondering why $\frac{\partial v^j }{\partial z^k}$ didn't come with a "$\Gamma$" and the reason is it is just a partial derivative, not a covariant derivative. On the other hand $\nabla_k v^j=\frac{\partial v^j}{\partial z^k}+\Gamma_{mk}^jv^m$

Comment: Exactly @ContraKinta

Comment: That's also exactly what I meant when I suggested to replace the first $\frac{\partial}{\partial Z^j}$ by $D_j$ or $\nabla_j$. It is total standard in every literature I have seen.

Comment: Welp @KurtG. I figured it out now

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out now. The answer was in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXitbCtbmBg&list=PLDS6JFNmWHR2-GFAR2ig7H9SRBavnBjC6&index=17).

Firstly, the most important thing to understand is the way the Covariant derivative acts on a vector and the way the derivative with coordinate acts is different. In the simplified case when were everything is calculated in $\mathbb{R^3}$, calculating the rate of change of the vector by the partials and by that of the connection is the same.

In the calculation I have shown above, we can the Christoffel popped out of the partial of the basis. Suppose we instead hit the vector with a connection:

$$ \nabla_{\alpha} (V) = \nabla_{\alpha} (V^i \vec{ Z_i})  = \nabla_{\alpha}(V^i) \vec{Z_i} + V^i \nabla_{\alpha} (\vec{Z_i})$$

Now the interesting point is that **the covariant derivative kills the basis**. We have,

$$ \nabla_{\alpha} (\vec{Z_i}) = \frac{\partial \vec{Z_i}}{\partial Z^k} - \Gamma_{ik}^m \vec{Z_m}$$

By the definition of the covariant derivative of a $(1,0)$ tensor. Now the thing is that $\frac{\partial \vec{Z_i} }{\partial Z^k} =  \Gamma_{ik}^m \vec{Z_m}$ , so the above expression evaluates to zero.

Comment: Welp shows that returning to the basis is helpful :D